# Google OAuth2.0 Using PHP and JSON for Service Accounts

Tags: php, json, google-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to use the Google API example to get OAuth2.0 working with my service account, but I'm having trouble with the sample code working without using the Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials since it's been deprecated.

The file is a JSON generated via the Service account page in the developer console.

Here's the snippet of the code.

```
// Create and configure a new client object.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("myApp");

$client->setAuthConfig($key_file_location);
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS);

if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getRefreshToken();
}

$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here, without answers yet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942676/setassertioncredentials-on-google-api-php-client-2-0

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to use a service account? The problem is likely that the library is expecting the JSON for an OAuth client rather than a service account.

Comment: Hey Patrick,I have created custom dimensions in GA and need to upload a CSV file to populate these dimensions. I want to use a service account to automate the process for uploading the CSV on a monthly basis.

Comment: Hi Jordi,  I tried your solution, but downloading the JSON for a new service account didn't help.